# Facebook Application Hosting

Tags: facebook

With the latest updates to Facebook and future upcoming changes, would I be able to develop apps hosted on a central domain? I.e., all of my apps will go on the back of https://www.myappdomain.com/ and structured as follows:

```
//https://www.myappdomain.com/clients/AppName1/ <br>
//https://www.myappdomain.com/clients/AppName2/ <br>
//https://www.myappdomain.com/clients/AppName3/ <br>
//https://www.myappdomain.com/clients/AppName4/ <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

We do this using subdomains and a wildcard certificate on mydomain.com. This gives more flexibility when setting up DNS I find.

```
https://client.myappdomain.com/
```

The only catch with this is that a wildcard certificate will only match one level of subdomain

`https://client.myappdomain.com/` will work

`https://app1.client.myappdomain.com/` will not work

To solve this, we conactenate the client and app name. This saves the cost of multiple wildcard certificates. So we end up with:

```
https://app1_client.myappdomain.com/
```

or

```
https://client_app1.myappdomain.com/
```

if you prefer.